# Firebase: Como obtener información al seleccinar un Item desde un selector

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Tengo una actividad que muestra en un `ListView` los datos obtenidos a través de un `tablaTiendas.orderByChild("empresa").equalTo(keyEmpresa).addValueEventListener`. El valor de `keyEmpresa` lo recibe desde otra actividad por `Intent`.

También tengo un `AutoCompleteTextView` el cual he llenado con datos obtenidos con un `tablaEmpresa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`y en donde puedo seleccionar uno de sus item que desencadenar un `setOnClickListener`. Todo esto funciona correctamente.

Pero lo que no consigo es que al seleccionar un item me actualice el `ListView` con el nuevo `keyEmpresa` recuperado del item seleccionado.

Había pensado poner el `tablaTiendas.orderByChild("empresa").equalTo(keyEmpresa).addValueEventListener` dentro del método que ejecuta el `setOnClickListener` pero creo que eso provocaría que se creara una nueva escucha para cada item seleccionado.

Aquí el código que tengo para cargar el ListView y el AutoCompleteTextView.

```
String keyEmpresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyEmpresa");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CARGA EL AutoCompleteTextView CON LOS NOMBRES DE EMPRESAS.
//
final ArrayAdapter adaptadorSelectorEmpresas = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listaEmpresas);

    DatabaseReference tablaEmpresa = firebase.getReferenciaNodo("empresa");
    tablaEmpresa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Empresa empresa;
        listaEmpresas.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot uid : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          empresa = uid.getValue(Empresa.class);
          empresa.setKey(uid.getKey());
          listaEmpresas.add(empresa);
        }
        selectorEmpresa = findViewById(R.id.cmpSelectorEmpresa);
        selectorEmpresa.setThreshold(1);
        selectorEmpresa.setAdapter(adaptadorSelectorEmpresas);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
    });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CARGA EL ListView CON LOS NOMBRES DE TIENDAS SEGUN SU keyEmpresa.
//
listViewTiendas = findViewById(R.id.lytListViewTiendas);
listViewTiendas.setOnItemClickListener(this);
listViewTiendas.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
adaptadorTiendas = new ListAdaptadorTienda(this, R.layout.tarjeta_2_campos, listaTiendas);

tablaTiendas.orderByChild("empresa").equalTo(keyEmpresa).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listaTiendas.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot uid : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          tienda = new Tienda();
          tienda = uid.getValue(Tienda.class);
          tienda.setKey(uid.getKey());
          listaTiendas.add(tienda);
        }
        listViewTiendas.setAdapter(adaptadorTiendas);
        adaptadorTiendas.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma. No se si es la más optima o la más "elegante".

Para actualizar el ListView he creado el método `llenarListView` el cual recibe como parámetro el valor por el que debe buscar en la BD. Observar que la escucha la almaceno en un objeto de tipo `ValueEventListener`.

```
private ValueEventListener escuchaTiendas;

  private void llenarListView(String keyEmpresa){
    escuchaTiendas = tablaTiendas.orderByChild("empresa").equalTo(keyEmpresa).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listaTiendas.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot uid : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          tienda = new Tienda();
          tienda = uid.getValue(Tienda.class);
          tienda.setKey(uid.getKey());
          listaTiendas.add(tienda);
        }
        listViewTiendas.setAdapter(adaptadorTiendas);
        adaptadorTiendas.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewTiendas.requestFocus();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
    });
  }
```

Para que al seleccionar un item del `AutoCompleteTextView` se ejecute el método `llenarListView` he modificado el evento `setOnItemClickListener`. Observar que primero comprueba que el objeto donde he guardado la escucha exista. En ese caso lo elimina para posteriormente volverlo a crear en el método `llenarListView`. El motivo de eliminar la escucha es porque por cada vez que se ejecute el método `llenarListView` se añadirá una nueva escucha a las que ya existan, lo cual no es correcto en este caso.

```
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //EVENTO PARA CUANDO SE SELECCIONA UNA EMPRESA DEL SELECTOR.
    selectorEmpresa.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (escuchaTiendas!=null){
          tablaTiendas.removeEventListener(escuchaTiendas);
        }
        String itemSeleccionado = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        for (Empresa t:listaEmpresas){
          if (itemSeleccionado.equals(t.getNombre())){
            keyEmpresa=t.getKey();
          }
        }
        llenarListView(keyEmpresa);
      }
    });
```